# Should I install the two packages in two different virtual environments?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two projects, p1 and p2, p1 depends on p2. p1 and p2 use the same other library but different versions of that library.

In such a case, should I install p1 and p2 in their own virtual environments so that each can use their own version of the other same library?

What's the best practice for such a case?

Comment: What do you mean by "p1 depends on p2"?  Do you mean that those are modules?  Are you talking about constructing a single executable?

Comment: As far as I know you can't have two versions of the same library in one environment/runtime.

Comment: Yes.  My thought too, if that's what you mean...you're talking about building a single executable.  You have to run everything in a single environment, and that environment can only have one version of each package.

Comment: @Steve, yes, I meant that I have to do "pip install p2" in order to run p1.

Comment: So I need 2 different virtual environments, right?

Comment: I recommend separate environments for separate projects. But that's not a rule, it is just an opinion, and it depends on the complexity of the projects. If p1 can be seen as a submodule of p2 (e.g. if there is no exclusive usecase for p1 without p2), I'd merge p1 and p2. And if you think you can pip install p1 with external package version 1 into an environment with external package version 2, then this would not work. You can only have one version of the same package in one environment. Is it important that p1 and p2 have different versions of the external package?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch, because p1 is controlled by others and if someday it uses a different version of library X that' would conflict with my current version of X in my project p2, that would create a trouble. Right? Isn't this should be a very common scenario?

Comment: If the APIs of the two versions differ, it can be that your two projects can become incompatible. This is a problem and the reason, why it is a best practise to raise DeprecationWarnings in some versions before actually breaking backwards compatibility. And this practise is the reason why broken dependencies actually are not a very common scenario.

Comment: Why is incompatible? Virtual environments serves this purpose exactly, by using different versions of the same library. Right?